# Any idea how to nginx reverse proxy on host connect to container via container name?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

im using docker for my applications and set up a nginx reverse proxy on my host where the docker containers are running. The Docker Container were created with docker-compose.

I would like to set up the upstream by container name and not ip address.
So I have this container and would like to talk with this via the name nginx

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                       NAMES
abcdefghijkl   nginx           "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   15 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8090->8090/tcp      nginx
```

The host cannot resolve the name to the ip. What I need to do?

```
curl nginx:8080
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nginx
```

PS: Curl with ip is working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used instead of the container name the mapped port on localhost.
So I connect to the container above with this:

```sh
curl localhost:8090
```